# Using tweepy getting tweet text showing 3 dots after some part of text instead the whole text

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I need to analyze the tweet for which i used tweepy to get the tweets but i am getting the part of tweet with 3 dots at the end

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=searchTerm, tweet_mode='extended').items(10):
    tweettext = str(tweet.full_text.lower().encode('ascii',  errors='ignore'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save full text of a tweet with tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588177/save-full-text-of-a-tweet-with-tweepy)

Comment: thanks it was actually a duplicate